# how to calculate the accuracy of data received from RTK-GPS?

Tags: sensors, gps

I have received data from an RTK-GPS, in an environment free from buildings and other GPS obstructions. the covariance of these data is 0.01. now I do not know this is good or not? How can I find out what is the accuracy of my GPS data? is there any solution?

latitude  longitude altitude position_covariance0 ... position_covariance4 ... position_covariance8 52.06669  -0.626525   156.98        0.0121                    0.0121                  0.1936

Thanks a lot

Comment: 0.01 _what_?  Meters?  Cubits?  Seconds of latitude?  Please _edit your question_ to include the correct engineering units.  Note that GPS with selective availability off (which I _think_ is now the case, permanently) has a CEP of around 10m in ideal conditions, but even in a flat field with a clear blue sky the conditions may not be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

How "good" the data is depends on how useful the results are for you.

The only way that you can check accuracy is to compare your measured results to a true result - this would require you to measure from a known location.

Comment: thanks , one more question what is the meaning of covariance in the output of GPS?   
header:
seq: 3583
stamp:
secs: 1626697000
nsecs: 617268281
frame_id: "novatel_mount_link"
status:
status: 2
service: 1
latitude: 52.0720616667
longitude: -0.627813333333
altitude: 150.98
position_covariance: [0.0004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0004, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0064]
position_covariance_type: 1               for instance in this output, what does covariance mean? and what is its unit?meter?centimeter?

Comment: @MasomeRahimi - You'd have to check with the manufacturer and/or the datasheet for the particular device.

Comment: If you have additional questions then please don't bury them in the comments.  If they're closely related to your original question (this one sure looks like it is) then _edit your question_ with the changes.  If it's completely different, then ask a new question.

Comment: @MasomeRahimi I fear you lack some statistics knowledge and you think to the concept of _accuracy_ as something like _tolerance_ 
You can mathematically get an _accuracy_ value based on the gathering GPS data for a while. But, reading your question, I think you are looking for something completely different

Comment: By the way: if you collect data from GPS you will see, that their distribution is not gaussian. For this reason, you have to check very carefully your statistic model. Furthermore, I do not know, where the _covariance of 0.01_ is coming from. Covariance, is not the first dimension I would look, when looking for accuracy. Stupid question: are you threating the X and Y and Z values (directions) separately?